# Why doesnt text-align:center; move my class="text5" to the center?

Tags: html, css, center

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Homepage</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="logo"><h2>Header Logo</h2></div>
        <div class="navbar">
            <ul> 
                <li><a href="index.html">header link one</a></li>
                <li><a href="index.html">header link two</a></li>
                <li><a href="index.html">header link three</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="text1"><h2>This website is awesome</h2></div>
        <div class="text2">This website has some subtext that goes here under the main title.It's a smaller font and the color is lower contrast
            <div class="button1">
                <div class="text4">Sign up</div>
            </div>
        </div>      
        <div class="placeholder">
        <div class="text3">this is  a placeholder for an image</div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container2">
        <div ID="text5"class="text5">
          Some random information.
        </div>
          <div class="box1" id="box1"></div>
          <div class="box2" id="box2"></div>
          <div class="box3" id="box3"></div>
          <div class="box4" id="box4"></div>
      </div>
    <div class="footer">
    Copyright © The Odin Project 2023
    </div>
    
</body>
</html>

* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  .container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 45vh;
    background-color: #1f2937;
    position: static;
    display: flex;  
  }

 
  
  .footer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 10vh;
    background-color: #1f2937;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
  }
  
  .logo {
    font-size: 24px;
    font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
    color: white;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding-top: 15px;
    font-family: 'Gill Sans', 'Gill Sans MT', Calibri, 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;
    padding-left: 200px;
    position: absolute; 
    top: 0;
  }
  
  .navbar {
    color:white;
    font-size: 18px;
    position: fixed;
    width: 85%;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: auto;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    flex-direction: row;
    padding-top: 15px;
    padding-right: 330px;
  }
  
  .navbar ul li {
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 20px; 
    text-decoration: none;
  }
  
  .text1 {
    position: relative;
    color: white;
    padding-left: 200px;
    font-size: 48px;
    font-weight: bold;
    width: 720px;
    top: 100px;
  }

  .text2 {
    position: relative;
    color: white;
    font-size: 18px;
    width: 400px;
    height: 200px;
    top: 300px;
    right: 520px;
  }


  .placeholder{
  position: relative;
  width: 500px;
  height:250px;
  background-color: grey;
  border: 2px solid grey;
  display:flex;
  top: 100px;
  right: 120px;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  color: white;
  } 

  .button1{
    border-radius: 5px;
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    font-weight: bold;
    border: 2px solid #3882F6;
    background-color:#3882F6;
    height:40px;
    width: 120px;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
  } 

  .container2{
    height: 45vh;
    background-color: white;
    position: relative;
    padding-top: 30px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
  } 
 
   #text5{
    font-size: 36px;
    font-weight:800;
    text-align: center;
  } 


  #box1, #box2, #box3, #box4{
    position: relative;
    border: 2px solid #3882F6;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    bottom: -100px;
    right: 250px;
    border-radius: 25px;  
    flex: 0 0 100px;
  }
```

Why doesn`t class="text5" move the text towards the center?As of right now the text is on the left hand side.
I've tried text-align=center but that did not result in anything. Does it have to do with Cascading?  I've also tried to put a width on it and margin: 0 auto; that moved the text but not to the center and messed up the spacing of my boxes.

Answer (score 2):

Text5 is a child of Container2, which is a flexbox. The flexbox controls the horizontal positioning of its children.

Perhaps you want to move Text5 outside Container2? perhaps before it?

Comment: Is there a way to center the text and keep it within the container2?

Comment: Remove `display: flex` from container2